# Count all foreach PHP

Tags: php

I've got a question:

I have the following code:

```
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value)  {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM producten WHERE id='$key'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $prijs = $row['prijs'];
        echo $prijs;
    }
 }
```

What I want to do is to count all the `$prijs` variables (`int`).
I tried to use `count($prijs)` but didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to sum up the values of `$prijs` ?

Comment: when you mean count? count how many $prjis? or get the sum of $prjis?

Comment: That sounds like `$result->num_rows` if you don't care if `prijs` are null

Comment: you can add your actual array var_dump so and explain what count you expected from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count of number of time loop, you can use counter variable and to get the sum up, you can use `+=` to sum the values in loop.

If you want to sum up only numeric values, you can use `is_numeric()` as well.

```
$i=0;
$sum=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $prijs = $row['prijs'];
   $sum += $prijs;
   $i++;
}
echo $i; //will give you count
echo $sum; //will give you sum
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem!

Comment: No problem, Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got your wording mixed up and you mean summing up the values of `$prijs`, in that case, use a new variable and add to it:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value)  {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM producten WHERE id='$key'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$prijs = $row['prijs'];
echo $prijs;
$sum += $prijs;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$i=0;                
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value)  {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM producten WHERE id='$key'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $prijs = $row['prijs'];  
         echo $prijs;
         $i++;
         echo $i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, `$prijs` will only returns single value, so when ever you are trying to `count` it will only gives a `1`. But if you want to set all the values come up and store as an array please try `$prijs[] = $row['prijs']`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code as follows:

```
$values = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', array_keys($_COOKIE));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM producten WHERE id in ('".implode("','",$values."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $prijs = $row['prijs'];
    echo $prijs;
}
echo "Total rows: ".$result->num_rows;
```